# css unwanted overlapping

Tags: css

Here is my html:

```
<div class="pagination">Page 
<a href="page.php?submit=1&amp;page=2">&#171;</a>
<a href="page.php?submit=1&amp;page=1">1</a>
<a href="page.php?submit=1&amp;page=2">2</a>
<strong>3</strong>
<a href="page.php?submit=1&amp;page=4">4</a> ...
<a href="page.php?submit=1&amp;page=104">104</a>
<a href="page.php?submit=1&amp;page=4">&#187;</a>
</div>
```

My css:

```
div.pagination                  { width: 90%; margin: 15px auto; float:right; text-align: right; }
div.pagination a                { border: 1px solid #0667B9; background-color:#B4D6F2; padding: 3px 6px; color:#0667B9; margin: 1px; }
div.pagination strong           { border: 1px solid #0667B9; background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 3px 6px; color:#0667B9; margin: 1px; }
div.pagination a:hover          { border: 1px solid #0667B9; background-color:#0667B9; padding: 3px 6px; color:#B4D6F2; margin: 1px; }
```

And what I am getting in result:
[image: Unwanted Css overlapping]

The problem you see, things are getting overlapped, what I would like to avoid.

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a line-height:30px; to div.pagination

Comment: Note that this will break if the user's font size is larger than you expect (e.g. if it's a 40px font, 30px will cause the letters to overlap).  It's usually better to set `line-height: 2` or some other relative quantity that will scale with the font size.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you used `float` I think.

Can you get away with using `display: inline` instead?

EDIT:

BTW I would have used list-items to display the paginator.

Comment: Thanks @PeeHaa, display inline could not get rid of the overlapping. list is a nice idea, I would give it a try next time.

Comment: 1up for advising the use of a list. That's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and it looks fine but try this

```
div.pagination a { border: 1px solid #0667B9; background-color:#B4D6F2; padding: 3px 6px; color:#0667B9; margin: 5px 10px; }
```

The padding pushes the border outside. So you might need some margin to push the links downward.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Adriano but this is not working by adding extra margin. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display:block; width:10px; float:left;
```

to

```
div.pagination a
```